# ImageMagick creates huge temporary files

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using imagick for GIF file uploads with resizing. Im used to upload filesizes ranges from 5mb -15mb
Due to huge tempory files my site gets crashed and also images are not getting converted correctly.
How can I fix this?

```
$imagick =  new Imagick($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

foreach ($imageFolders as $imageFolder => $size) {

    if ($imagick->getImageWidth() > $size['minWidth']) {
        $width = $size['maxWidth'];
        $height = $size['maxWidth'];
    } else {
        $width = $imagick->getImageWidth();
        $height = $imagick->getImageHeight(
    }

    $imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();

    foreach($imagick as $frame){
        $frame->thumbnailImage($width , $height ); 
        $frame->setImagePage($width , $height , 0, 0); 
    }

    $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();
    $imagick->writeImages($imagePath, true);

}

$imagick->clear();
```

Comment: Are you able to move the resize operations outside of your web server / thread? A 15mb gif w/ LZW can easily expand pass 60mb during decompression. Without seeing your code, you could have introduced an allocation leak that's eating all your resources.

Comment: @emcconville  Ive updated my questions with the code. Is there any fix where I can do using policy.xml or configure.xml files from imagick. pls advice

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, it is related to imageMagic. I got this link https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/395. To fix this, I have created a cronjob which runs every minute and deletes the tmp file. 
Here is the shell script

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "magick-*" -delete
```

If anyone has better alternative, please suggest.

Comment: can't we fix this without uisng a cron

Comment: @SandFer, I don't know till now, even I am searching an alternative solution for this.